# How does Symfony `url()` Twig function determine the Absolute Path when executed in CLI?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, command-line-interface, absolute-path

Let's pretend that our **Twig template** contain the following code: `{{ absolute_url(path('__Controller__')) }}` or `{{ url('__Controller__') }}`.

When Twig generate the HTML while being executed inside a **Symfony** (ie: 2.7) command containing the functions above, how does the absolute path is determinated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It reads it from [RequestContext](https://github.com/symfony/routing/blob/2.8/RequestContext.php). Which gets automatically populated from request data during HTTP request, but needs to be set explicitly in CLI environment.

You can either configure it manually:

```
$context = $this->container->get('router')->getContext();
$context->setHost('mydomain.com');
$context->setScheme('https');
```

Or let Symfony do it automatically for you by setting up the following parameters:

```
# app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
    router.request_context.host: mydomain.com
    router.request_context.scheme: https
```

Symfony docs have an article explaining this: https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/console/request_context.html